# cryptogen extend is generating the certificates even when there is no crypto-config folder? Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was experimenting with the `cryptogen` binary commands.

As we know that `generate` keyword generates the new certificates as per the `crypto-config.yaml` and default `output crypto-config` folder.

I run the `extend` command when there is no `crypto-config`. So it generates the new `crypto-config`.

Isn't it should give an error? As network certificates should first `generate` then only can be `extend`.

Is there any drawback if I use `extend` keyword in place of `generate` every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**extend** sub command does check if a sub directory with the domain name specified in the config file exists inside the input directory (default being crypto-config) or not. If the check fails then it just does the same task as is achieved by running the **generate** sub command otherwise it generates the extra crypto material. **extend** is  used to generate crypto material for an additional peer for an organization whose crypto material is already generated.

So you can run the extend command without running the generate command but it is **not recommended** as there will always be an overhead of an extra file system check.

**EDIT**: I think that I was a bit unclear earlier. So I just wanted to mention that there will be an overhead of multiple file system checks while running the extend command, which will be due to checks for each of the mentioned organization in the specified config file.